# Key event listening

Tags: android, keyboard

Can someone give me a quick crash course in using the physical keypad for android?

I have this method in my code:

```
public boolean OnKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode) {

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

yet when i press the physical 1 button in the emulator nothing happens.

am i missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Step #1: Add the `@Override` annotation.

Step #2: When the compiler complains that there is no `OnKeyDown` method, rename it to `onKeyDown()`. :-)

Comment: Something would need to call this method though, wouldn't it or will it be accessed whenever the user presses a hard keyboard key?